# images within a <div> is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

***functionality:***

I have created 2 `<div>` with different id name. The 2 different `<div>` will do an ajax call to retrieve a set of images so that the images retrieved will be displayed.

In summary, 2 different  id name are calling on the same ajax method to retrieve a set of images to display.

***What has been done:***

I have created the 2 different `<div>`. I have referenced the 1st and 2nd div to same ajax call and finally I append it to the `<div>` id

Code:

```js
$("#page_content").on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
    retrievePost(true);
  }
});

$("#displayPage").on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
    retrievePost(true);
  }
});

HideShowDiv()

var num_post = 30;
var display_page = 0;
var venueID = 99;

function retrievePost(isAppend) {
  ajax_retrieveImages("imagesocial.do", "formType=retrieveServerImages&venueID=" + venueID + "&num=" + num_post + "&page=" + display_page, isAppend);
}


// Function call for the FIRST DIV ID: TO CALL ON AJAX METHOD TO RETRIEVE IMAGES

function HideShowDiv() {

  retrievePost(false);
  display_page = 0;
}

// Function call for the SECOND DIV ID: TO CALL ON AJAX METHOD TO RETRIEVE IMAGES

$("#IGram").click(function() {
  console.log(this.id);

  $("#MainMenu").fadeOut(function() {
    $("#NPage").fadeIn();
  })

   retrievePost(false);
  display_page = 0;
})
```

```html
<div id="M_Start" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index=1; top:0px; left:0px;">

  <div id="IDisplayPage" style="position:absolute;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1080">
      <tr>
        <td width="1080" align="center">

          <!-- FIRST DIV ID: TO CALL ON AJAX METHOD TO RETRIEVE IMAGES-->
          <div id="displayPage" style="position:absolute; z-index:2; top:1020px; left:22px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; height:820px; width:1050px;"></div>


        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="NPage" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=3; top:0px; left:0px;">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1080">
    <tr>
      <td width="1080" align="center">

        <!-- SECOND DIV ID: TO CALL ON AJAX METHOD TO RETRIEVE IMAGES-->

        <div id="page_content" style="position:absolute; z-index:2; top:1020px; left:22px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; height:820px; width:1050px;"></div>


      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

***ISSUE:***

When I run the program, only 1 of the `<div>` shows the retrieved images, the other `<div>` remains blank. Hence, only `<div id="page_content" ....>` is showing the list of images that have been retrieved from the ajax call, the other `<div id="displayPage"..... >` is displaying a blank div, no list of images is displayed. When I do check on the developer code, there is no error.

What has happen?? please help.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to share the `instagram_retrievePost` method as well

Comment: is this the full code? where are the instagram_... functions. Seems like you are using variables before they are initialised. Do improve on your phrasing of question.

Comment: @ArunPJohny   apologies, I have edited the code, `instagram_retrievePost` is actually `retrievePost `.

Comment: @zaclerv  apologies, I have edited the code, instagram_retrievePost is actually retrievePost .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retrieve function is perhaps having a hardcoded div id that appends the results to the same div. You might want to use $(this) and find the appropriate context for the call and swap the div ids.

Comment: I dont get what you mean

Comment: You have to post the code of ajax_retrieveImages which I assume has the callback function that processes the data that comes back from the server.

Comment: If it helped and you have solved your issue, please accept my answer.